# Replace values in a series pandas

Tags: python, regex, pandas, replace, series

How come when i want to replace a value I have to use this block of code:

```
data['Organization'].str.replace('Greece','Rome')
```

why cant I use this:

```
data['Organization'].replace('Greece','Rome').
```

I've seen others use method two before without passing a string method. 
My question is can i pass a series method using replace function and what is the line of code?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`pd.Series.replace` is different to `pd.Series.str.replace`:

- [`pd.Series.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.replace.html) is used to replace an element in its entirety. It will work also on non-string elements.
- [`pd.Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) is used to replace substrings, optionally using regex.

Here's a minimal example demonstrating the difference:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': ['foo', 'fuz', np.nan]})

df['B'] = df['A'].replace(['foo', 'fuz'], ['food', 'fuzzy'])
df['C'] = df['A'].str.replace('f.', 'ba', regex=True)

print(df)

     A      B    C
0  foo   food  bao
1  fuz  fuzzy  baz
2  NaN    NaN  NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

`str.replace` by default does a regex based replacement which also works with partial matches. `replace`, OTOH, will only perform replacements based on full matches by default unless the `regex` flag is set to true.

```
data['Organization'] = (
    data['Organization'].replace({'Greece': 'Rome'}, regex=True))
```